# error Expected 1 line break before closing bracket, but no line breaks\ found vue/html-closing-bracket-newline

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

My current **.eslintrc.js** file has these options set for the [eslint-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue)
plugin:

```
"vue/html-closing-bracket-newline": ["error", {
    "singleline": "never",
    "multiline": "always"
    }]
```

The problem this accepts only this syntax:

```
<v-flex                                                                     
  xs12                                                                      
>                                                                           
  <Test />                                                                  
</v-flex>
```

How can I ask it to let me write this way instead:

```
<v-flex                                                                     
  xs12>                                                                           
  <Test />                                                                  
</v-flex>
```

If I write the last syntax, ESLint complains:

```
error  Expected 1 line break before closing bracket, but no line breaks\
 found  vue/html-closing-bracket-newline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/html-closing-bracket-newline.md#multiline-never)

```
"multiline": "never"
```

... should fix your issue. Unfortunately, there's no way the rule can be implemented to accept both. It's either `never` or `always`.
Your pick. But Vue **strongly** suggests `always`.